# Eth0 turns on with DHCP after reboot

Tags: 12.04, networking, server

I have SUPERMICRO SYS-5015A-EHF-D525 with IPMI and am having a strange problem during reboot.  I am running  Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS server.

The "primary" network interface that is being used for activity is eth1.  It is set to a static address of 10.10.35.70 (see code below).

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
#auto eth1
#iface eth1 inet dhcp

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
        address 10.10.35.70
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 10.10.35.1
        dns-nameservers 208.67.222.222 208.67.220.220
```

The IPMI interface shares eth0.  I thought it was disabled, but on reboot it acts as if it is setup for dhcp and grabs and IP address.  The IPMI interface is setup to use 10.10.35.71, but it not set in Ubuntu. Output of ifconfig after reboot:

```
~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:90:c8:0b:98
          inet addr:10.10.35.100  Bcast:10.10.35.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::225:90ff:fec8:b98/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1032849 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:427403 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:194936769 (194.9 MB)  TX bytes:62104825 (62.1 MB)
          Interrupt:16 Memory:fe9e0000-fea00000

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:90:c8:0b:99
          inet addr:10.10.35.70  Bcast:10.10.35.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::225:90ff:fec8:b99/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4089738 errors:0 dropped:1400 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1561324 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:3533629321 (3.5 GB)  TX bytes:149875516 (149.8 MB)
          Interrupt:17 Memory:feae0000-feb00000

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:7628905 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7628905 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:1978672469 (1.9 GB)  TX bytes:1978672469 (1.9 GB)
```

When the system reboots the dual IP addresses causes problems for routing and connectivity in some cases.  I can run `sudo ifconfig eth0 down` but would like to determine a way to prevent the eth0 from obtaining an IP address in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a stanza for your eth0 card in `/etc/network/interfaces` with the line, this will stop network manager doing its thing.

```
iface eth0 inet manual
```

Comment: Just tired rebooting the machine and confirmed that it solves the problem.